# Total sum of random array values

Tags: c#, arrays, random

So we created an application in our last chapter that generated and displayed a set of random numbers ranging from 0-99. For our "new" assignment, we are being asked to add a label and textbox to present the total of the random values that are displayed each time we generate a new set. I've found the section in my textbook that describes how the code is written to total the values, but not when they are randomized. I've been racking my brain trying to search for a solution online but either the programming language is different or the values being totaled aren't randomized. Can someone walk me through how to go about this?

```
    private void generateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create an array to hold the numbers.
        const int SIZE = 5;
        int[] lotteryNumbers = new int[SIZE];

        // Create a Random object.
        Random rand = new Random();

        // Fill the array with random numbers, in the range // of 0 through 99.
        for (int index = 0; index < lotteryNumbers.Length; index++)
        {
            lotteryNumbers[index] = rand.Next(100);
        }

        // Display the array elements in the Label controls.
        firstLabel.Text = lotteryNumbers[0].ToString();
        secondLabel.Text = lotteryNumbers[1].ToString();
        thirdLabel.Text = lotteryNumbers[2].ToString();
        fourthLabel.Text = lotteryNumbers[3].ToString();
        fifthLabel.Text = lotteryNumbers[4].ToString();
    }

    private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Close the form.
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: `lotteryNumbers.Sum()` ?

Comment: @David Showing Linq codes to beginners is like giving them cheat codes in games.

Comment: @Han: LINQ is hardly a "cheat" or some kind of guarded secret.  It's a tool to do a job.  If one requires that someone can't use efficient tools, where does that requirement end?  Is C# too efficient a tool?  Is object oriented programming or structured programming too efficient a tool?  Should they solve the problem with nothing more than a logic board and a soldering iron?

Comment: @David A simple addition in the loop is enough.

Comment: @Han: A simple method call is also enough.  There are multiple ways to solve a problem.

Comment: `...or the values being totaled aren't randomized`  randomized values do not sum any differently than ordered or sequential values.  the arithmetic is the same

Comment: No jumping at each other. Ya'll I've barely been surviving this class. I'm typically pretty adept with picking up new skills, especially at beginner levels but I can't grasp a damn thing about programming. My teacher is of no help whatsoever, never helps us herself, only tells us to go to the only programming tutor on campus we have (who is only there two hours a week during my work hours). I'm barely hanging on to a decent grade. It's been somewhat simple because a lot of the things she asks for are directly in the text but she doesn't teach use how to do anything *ourselves*.

Comment: I'm dreading my GPA slipping because it's taken me so long to get it to where it is and most of my successful assignments have been with the help of paying online tutors (who sucked and did the problems for me rather than explaining anything so I could actually grasp it) and I just can't afford it anymore but I don't understand anything for the life of me. I'm not asking for "cheat codes" thank you, and I'm aware especially with this post that it's clear that I'm not cut out for this but I'm trying to understand how to create what I need to create to make it through this class.

Comment: Using Linq is perfectly legal. It just hides implementation of the functions, eg. Sum() which is a function that gives total of a collection of values. See David's answer. The logic of calculating total is in the loop body. But if you use Linq like in David's second code, it hides the calculation. This is important if you are new to programming. You must get a clear understanding how to do it. After you know how to do it like David's first sample, you can use a more advanced technique like Linq.

Comment: *"Can someone walk me through how to go about this?"* Two good rules for beginner and expert programmers alike are: (1) if there's a concept you want to represent, then declare a variable of the appropriate type and then think about what to do with it. You want to represent a sum? OK: `int sum = 0;`.  Now we have a program. It's *wrong* because the sum isn't actually zero. How do we make it right?  **Probably by adding something to something else**.  What should be added?  And now we're moving towards a solution; we started moving because we declared a variable.

Comment: (2) If there's a problem you can't solve, then *there is an easier problem that you can solve*.  If you had an array of two elements, how would you sum them?  You can write that program probably.  Now, what about three?  Four? Five?  Now, can you rewrite your program *in terms of repeated operations on the sum variable*?  If you can, then you can transform your programs into one that uses a loop.

Comment: The larger question embedded in your rant in the comments above is: *I'm not getting an adequate education for my money*. That's not a problem that SO can help you with; if you're posting here, stay focussed on the coding problem. There are lots of things you can do to solve your pedagogy problem: find a better tutor, watch videos, get a beginner C# book, whatever. Heck, **learning a different programming language** would probably help; take a *JavaScript* tutorial on Khan Academy or something; at your current level JS and C# differ only in small details. We can't help you with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to get the sum of the values generated in your loop, you can use your existing loop for that.  Consider the following logical structure:

```
// declare a value
// loop
    // add to the value
// end loop
// use the value
```

Applying this structure to your code might look something like this:

```
int sumTotal = 0;
for (int index = 0; index < lotteryNumbers.Length; index++)
{
    lotteryNumbers[index] = rand.Next(100);
    sumTotal += lotteryNumbers[index];
}
// any time after this, you can display "sumTotal"
```

---

Conversely, many simple operations like this are achievable using some handy structures/tools in the .NET framework itself.  For example, there [are a *variety* of useful extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods.aspx) on collections like `IEnumerable<T>`, which support simple arrays as well.  You *could* get the sum of a collection with a single method call:

```
int sumTotal = lotteryNumbers.Sum();
```

(You would of course have to do this *after* your loop, otherwise there won't be anything to sum.)

Comment: So in order to have this sum displayed in the textbox I'm supposed to have, would I use a ToString method? I'm fair with displaying things that are already resolved in a MessageBox, but I'm awful with displaying data in textboxes. The whole concept of what can or can't be displayed or what needs to be converted and the like isn't a concept that's taken a liking to me.

Comment: @ToriTarantino: That sounds like a question; you're on a question-and-answer site. Consider posting another question!  But in general: if you are trying to convert something to text for display purposes, `ToString` is certainly a good first guess.

Comment: @ToriTarantino: I suspect you're drastically overthinking this.  There's no magic behind it.  You already have a working example of displaying an integer value to the user, right?  `firstLabel.Text = lotteryNumbers[0].ToString();`  Why would displaying *another* integer value be any different at all?  This may all seem complex, because you're trying to keep it all in your head at once.  Complex things are made of many simple things.  Adding two numbers together is simple.  Displaying something to the user is simple.  Etc.

Comment: Oh I definitely know I'm overthinking it lol. I'm just never able to de-stress enough to look at and understand all of the little things that make up the bigger picture when I've already determined I'm stressed out over the picture itself lol. But thank you for your help, I seriously appreciate it. Just a couple more weeks of this class and I'm going to test new waters. Glad I gave the the *literal* "old college try".

Comment: Anyways, I got it. It made more sense after you called out my unnecessary panicking lol. Thank you again, seriously.

Answer (score 0):

So you'd want a variable that can hold your result.

lotteryNumbers holds your random numbers. so you would have to iterate through your numbers and add the individual value to your result variable.

Some pseudo code would look like this

```
declare resultVariable

loop all numbers in lotteryNumbers
   add current number in lotteryNumbers to resultVariable
```